# Firemonkey Mouse Right Click Event Simulation

Tags: delphi, mouseevent, firemonkey

I'm experiencing problems in popping-up a popup menu via statement;
This is the code:

```
P := Button1.LocalToAbsolute(TPointF.Create(Button1.Width / 2,Button1.Height / 2));
PopupMenu1.Popup(P.X,P.Y);
```

Firemonkey (Delphi XE6) pops up the menu, but the TMenuItems are not shown with their Hightlight features (light text over dark background).
The TMenuItems seem not active.
But If I right-Click on the button everything works fine.
I think that this si a bug of Firemonkey, so I would fire a Right-Click event if a certain condition is satisfied.
Is it possible to do so in Firemonkey ?

Comment: Nope, it is a type. It is Button1.

Comment: Not it is correct.
However, do you have a system to fire a right click event programmatically ?